# Differences between Win32 WNetUseConnection and System.IO to access network fileshares

Tags: c#, smb

I have a server in Azure running an application that needs to access a file share OnPrem to count files in a folder. For this SMB 3.1.1 has with all the security bells and whistles has been set up (all traffic goes over an ExpressRoute). The domain in Azure is not trusted OnPrem so I need to connect using impersonation.

In order to achieve this, I'm using this (the whole code is 140 lines, but these are the main functions):

```
    private const int RESOURCETYPE_DISK = 0x00000001;
    private const int CONNECT_INTERACTIVE = 0x00000008;
    private const int CONNECT_PROMPT = 0x00000010;
    private const int CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE = 0x00000001;

    [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetUseConnection(IntPtr hwndOwner, NETRESOURCE lpNetResource, string lpPassword, string lpUserID, int dwFlags, string lpAccessName, string lpBufferSize, string lpResult);

    [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string lpName, int dwFlags, bool fForce);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private class NETRESOURCE
    {
        public int dwScope = 0;
        public int dwType = 0;
        public int dwDisplayType = 0;
        public int dwUsage = 0;
        public string lpLocalName = "";
        public string lpRemoteName = "";
        public string lpComment = "";
        public string lpProvider = "";
    }

    private NetworkShareAccessor(string remoteComputerName, string userName, string password)
    {
        RemoteComputerName = remoteComputerName;
        UserName = userName;
        Password = password;

        ConnectToShare(_remoteUncName, UserName, Password, false);
    }

    private void ConnectToShare(string remoteUnc, string username, string password, bool promptUser)
    {
        NETRESOURCE nr = new NETRESOURCE
        {
            dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK,
            lpRemoteName = remoteUnc
        };

        int result;
        if (promptUser)
        {
            result = WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, "", "", CONNECT_INTERACTIVE | CONNECT_PROMPT, null, null, null);
        }
        else
        {
            result = WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, password, username, 0, null, null, null);
        }

        if (result != NO_ERROR)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(result);
        }
    }
```

And then counting the files using this piece of code:

```
            using (NetworkShareAccessor.Access(config.ServerIp, config.Domain, config.User, config.Password))
            {
                string path = @"\\"+ config.ServerIp + config.targetPath;

                var fileCount = (from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*")
                                 select file).Count();
            }
```

For accessing our file share from OnPrem (in the same domain on the same network) I just do a:

```
            var fileCount = (from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(config.Path, "*.*")
                             select file).Count();
```

I see that when I run the first approach, either from OnPrem to the fileshare OR from Azure to the same File share it takes everything from 79ms to 30'000ms to run and quite often fails with the error "***System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): A device attached to the system is not functioning***"

If I run the second approach (which I can't run from Azure to OnPrem due to the impersonation etc) the timings are between 7ms to 80ms (over 1000 attempts) without any errors.

My question is if there's something wrong in the code or if there's something that makes the first approach using that **WNetUseConnection** less robust and much more time consuming? Or is it indicative of issues with the fileshare itself and the way it communicates?

I've tried searching online to see what the differences are "under the hood", but so far I haven't been able to find much of use.

Comment: If you are using a domain user then you need line of sight to the domain's DC. Using an IP address is also a bit suspect, you should use the fully qualified domain name instead.

Comment: Well, it has. And when I tried running it from the OnPrem server to the OnPrem fileshare I used the FQDN instead of the IP, but it still gives me an error rate of around 20% of all the polls I do.

If I only switch it to go the "normal" .NET way (using System.IO), not only is it orders of magnitude faster, it also never fails. But unfortunately, this approach won't work from Azure to OnPrem since the Azure DNS isn't aware of the OnPrem servers and vice versa and they're in different domains, so then , the only way I've found to work is using invoking mpr.dll and call WNet.

Comment: In the definition of `NETRESOURCE` I think `public string lpLocalName = "";` is wrong, as you are supposed to set it to null not an empty string (ie don't bother initializing). Same for the other string fields. You always need some kind of line of sight to a DC otherwise you can;t authenticate to the domain. Azure has its own way of doing that, ExpressRoute is one of them. Possibly something going wrong with that?

Comment: Might be worth checking your networking setup on the client machine, it sounds like it might be trying over the wrong network adapter first.